# Двоякое where in в MS SQL

Tags: sql, if, case

Есть некий построитель отчётов - Pentaho Report Designer.
В нём удобно задать визуал для пользователя и т.д.

Вот, пример отчёта и подставляемых параметров (сверху):
[image: Отчёт]

Для построения выполняется 2 запроса:

1. Заполнение чекбокса территории;
2. Построение графика по выбранному периоду и территориям.

Проблема в том, что в БД нет значения `Не задано`. Вместо него там стоит `NULL`. Переименование идёт в первом запросе, дабы не резать глаза пользователю.
Но, когда я выполняю запрос на построение графика, то значение `Не задано` естественно не находит.

**Вопрос:**
Как указать в запросе в условии, чтобы если `Территория РФ = Не задано`, то брать `NULL`?

Запрос который у меня сейчас есть и отрабатывает на все территории, кроме `Не задано`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [BD1].[dbo].[Testing]
WHERE [Территория РФ] IN (${Areas})
```

**${Areas}** - синтаксис для отчёта (объект "Территория")

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)
Nov 1 2020 00:48:37
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 (Build 9200: )
(Hypervisor)

Comment: В 2014 sql сервере есть поддержка `case` в условии `where`, попробуйте поменять условие `WHERE case when [Территория РФ] is null then 'Не задано' else [Территория РФ] end in (${Areas})`

Comment: @ipatev_nn, спасибо! Получился нужный результат. Думал что нужно использовать `case`, но как точно написать не удавалось

Comment: Ну и ещё есть не только IFNULL(), но и практически обратная ей функция NULLIF(), очень как раз подходящая для  *если Территория РФ = Не задано, то брать NULL*: `NULLIF([Территория РФ], 'Не задано')`.

Comment: @Akina, не слышал про это, но интересно. Она спокойно отработает в конструкции с `where`?

Comment: WHERE глубочайшим образом начхать, что там у неё под юбкой делается. Её заботит только одно - чтобы всё выражение возвращало булев тип (или, в системах с мягким типом данных, способное приводиться к булеву). А внутри хоть качучу пляши.

Comment: @Akina, ок, буду в курсе